# Convert audio to text

Tags: c#, java, speech-recognition, audio-processing

I just want to know if there is any build in libraries or external libraries in Java or C# that allow me to take an audio file and parse it and extract the text from it.

I need to make an application to do so, but I don't know from where I can start.

Comment: definitely not built-in. I take it that you wish to extend your questions to libraries you can use from Java or C#.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Thilo , ok if you know any external libraries of C# or Java that can do what i want i will be appreciated if you tell me , Thanks in Advance

Comment: This might might help  http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/reference/codesamples/index.html

Comment: In c# you  can use Speech API.refer this 


   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125077%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Extract text from audio?! Are you for real???

Comment: @Cipi OCR extracts text from images and there's plenty of work being done to do the same for audio.  Just check youtube for the computer generated closed-captioning.  For the laughs, I mean.  They're horrible, but so was OCR at the beginning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some of your options:

- [Microsoft Speech](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Lumenvox](http://www.lumenvox.com/products/speech_engine/)
- [Dragon naturally speaking](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon/index.htm)
- [sphinx4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a complete example using C# and System.Speech

The code can be divided into 2 main parts:

configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine object (and its required elements)
handling the SpeechRecognized and SpeechHypothesized events.

**Step 1: Configuring the SpeechRecognitionEngine**

```
_speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
_speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
_dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
_speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);
_speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

At this point your object is ready to start transcribing audio from the microphone. You need to handle some events though, in order to actually get access to the results.

**Step 2: Handling the SpeechRecognitionEngine Events**

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized -= new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler(SpeechRecognized);
>   _speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler(SpeechHypothesizing);
>
> private void SpeechHypothesizing(object sender,
>   SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e) { 
>   ///real-time results from the engine
>   string realTimeResults = e.Result.Text; }
>
> private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs
>   e) { 
>   ///final answer from the engine string finalAnswer =
>   e.Result.Text; }

That’s it. If you want to use a pre-recorded .wav file instead of a microphone, you would use

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(pathToTargetWavFile);

instead of

> _speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

There are a bunch of different options in these classes and they are worth exploring in more detail.

http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/

Answer (score 1):

You might check [Microsoft Speech API](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/default.aspx). I think they provide a SDK that you can use for your objective.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, it seems there is a solution from Sun: [javax.speech.recognition](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/Recognition.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SoX (the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs) to convert audio file to text file with numeric values corresponding to sound frequency/volume.

I have done it for a previous project but don't know the exact command options.

Here is a link to the project: http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage