# Stream audio from shockwave player into c# voice recognition api

Tags: c#, asynchronous, shockwave

So I have no code to present here because I don't even know if this is possible.

I have a shockwave player link that I grabbed from a local website. It transmits live audio.

I want to take that live audio and pipe it into the C# voice recognition api and process what is being said as it runs.

Is this even possible?

Comment: [C# Speech Recognition from System Audio (Speaker Sound)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422717/c-sharp-speech-recognition-from-system-audio-speaker-sound?rq=1)

Comment: @Prix haha okay I didn't think a hack like that would be suggested so I suppose I should update the tags. I want to do a windows phone app. I just left that out because I wanted more C# focused answers