# Converting Audio Files to Text in C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, audio, text, speech-recognition

I need to convert audio files, being specific mp3 files to simple Text, and then converting back that text to mp3 again, one of feature of my mobile application, is it possible? if Yes, then how? guideline please.

Comment: what kind of text do you expect? Are you looking for bits and bytes or some kind of mathematical equation that lies behind the mp3?

Comment: you mean to save binary data in txt file?

Comment: @GameDroids, No just the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer for audio to text [here (second post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958342/convert-audio-to-text)

For the text to audio, i would use any Text-to-Speech. In c# you could also use System.Speech.

Comment: I visited that link that wasn't my answer, well found the way to do it. Its simple just change the extension .mp3 or whatever to .txt using DOS command : ren example.mp3 example.txt.

Comment: *"just change the extension .mp3 or whatever to .txt"*  That is nonsense.  The file content is still an MP3.

Comment: I have to do nothing with the content, what I needed mp3 to be converted in Text representation.

Comment: but what are you planning on doing with the text file after you changed the extension?