# Convert audio to text programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, audio

I want to convert audio that is in `.mp3` and `.wav` to text..
I write

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
```

but shows error of missing assembly.
I read many articles and questions here but did not understand first what to do.
Also tried to install `speech.dll` but shows error of

> please make sure file is accessible and valid assembly or COM component`

any link from where I can download?

If any one can explain me step by step of installation plz. I am newbie to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert audio to text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958342/convert-audio-to-text)

Comment: @Dmitry I read that but I want to know about installation or dll part..I didnot get anything from any articles :(

Answer (score 1):

`System.Speech` is part of the .NET Framework. To install it, right-click your project in Visual Studio and add a reference:

[image]

In the next window select `System.Speech` under *Assemblies/Framework* and press OK:

[image]

You can now reference the System.Speech package. Simply type your code and add your using statement:

[image]